# Javascript animation with recursion, strange behavior

Tags: javascript, animation, recursion

Im trying to do code in javascript a ruzzle solver. For now it just dig through the maze and find every  possible path ( in the future I will match them against a dictionary to find the real valid words in it)

You can see it here : `http://178.239.177.105/ruzzle/`

I wanted to do it with an animation that show how the algorithm works on it, but im issuing a problem.
If you load it, the page just dont show anything, and my browser crash after a while.

BUT...

if you set an alert("") function, somewhere in the middle of the recursion function, you would be able to go through any step in the algorithm.
Especially if you set the browser to prevent to show any further alert messages, you'll finally see the animation working on the maze.

I was actually trying to do this via setInterval(), but is not working.

So I have two questions:
- Why do the script cause the page to crash, or not if there's an alert?
- How can I properly show the animation using some kind on wait() mechanism?

Thanks

You can **see all the code** by going on the page and look at the source code, however for the sake of clarity I'll paste the relevant code here:

You can also **play with the code** here : http://jsfiddle.net/Gcw2U/
(you will have to uncomment the last line in the  to make it run)

```
        //this matrix of chars rapresent the 4x4 puzzle
          var ruzle_model = [["w","a","l","k"],["m","o","o","n"],["h","a","t","e"],["r","o","p","e"]];



        // ""offsets" rapresent the four motion vector(up,down,left,right)
        // used to visit the matrix
        var offsets = [[1,0],[0,1],[-1,0],[0,-1]];

//recursive function to dig the maze
            function path(m,i,j,paths,checkeds){
                alert("SET BROWSER TO AVOID NEXT ALERTS MSGs!");
                //base case, if not hitting a wall or already checked cell
                if ( ! (i<=3 && i>=0 && j>=0 && j<=3) || isChecked(checkeds,i,j)){
                    terminal.innerHTML = terminal.innerHTML + "-"+ paths;
                    uncheckAllCells();
                    return paths;
                    }

                //call path for every direction (up,down,left,right) stored in offsets
                var tmp = [];
                for (var c=0; c<offsets.length;++c){
                    var offset = offsets[c];
                    checkCells(i,j);
                    checkeds.push(new Array(i,j));
                    tmp.push(path(m,i+offset[0],j+offset[1],paths + m[i][j],copy(checkeds)));
                }

                return tmp;
            }


            //call path on every cell in the maze
            function ruzzle(r){
                var sol = []
                for(var i=0; i<4; ++i){
                    for(var j=0; j<4; ++j){
                        var checkeds = new Array();
                        sol.push(path(r,i,j,'',checkeds));
                    }
                }
                terminal.innerHTML = sol;
                return sol;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript loops and recursions inhibit rendering of the page, so any changes made will stay invisible until the script stops executing, like when you spawn an `alert`. When a user sets "do not show alert messages", the alert still yields execution time to the underlying eventloop, which will update the page.

For as-fast-as-possible (high fps) animations, use `requestAnimationFrame()`.

In your case, `setTimeout()` is the best way to go. Set a timeout on the recursive call to `path`.

```
function recursive(args) {
    // do stuff to args
    setTimeout(function () {
        recursive(args);
    }, 5);
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6rmJe/)

Comment: Thanks for the example. I Tried and it behave super strangely.

Like this, change completely the output:

     `setTimeout(function(){ tmp.push(path(m,i+offset[0],j+offset[1],paths + m[i][j],copy(checkeds)));
     },500); `

Like this, applied just on the `path` function is even worse, it start to print numbers!!


`tmp.push(setTimeout(function(){ path(m,i+offset[0],j+offset[1],paths + m[i][j],copy(checkeds));
     },500)); `

Comment: I guess you have to refactor your algorithm. I can't see a solution that will work with your code as-is. Try to change it so that you pass your output array in the function arguments, instead of relying on return.